# How to store JSON return Value in Sharedpreferene

Tags: android, json, android-sharedpreferences

I am getting android apps crash problem. Actually I am trying to store json return value in the sharedPreference in android apps. Which have no error but apps is continue crash and I try uninstalling apps multiple time and there is no progress.I don't know about mistake, again I am new shared preference actually this app used sqllite before I change it. **I am trying to store json return data in sharedpreferance here is my loginActivity file:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request.Method;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.R;
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppConfig;
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.app.AppController;
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.helper.SessionManager;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnLogin;
    private Button btnLinkToRegister;
    private EditText inputEmail;
    private EditText inputPassword;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        // Login button Click Event
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

                // Check for empty data in the form
                if (!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    // login user
                    checkLogin(email, password);
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }

        });

        // Link to Register Screen
        btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * function to verify login details in mysql db
     * */
    private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
        // Tag used to cancel the request
        String tag_string_req = "req_login";

        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
                AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (!error) {
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Create login session
                        session.checkLogin();

                        // Now store the user in SQLite
                        String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                        JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                        int id   =   user.getInt("id");
                        String name = user.getString("name");
                        String email = user.getString("email");
                        String status = user.getString("status");

                        session.createLoginSession(email,password,id);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("status",status);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        // Error in login. Get the error message
                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                hideDialog();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And The **SessionManager** is:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.HashMap;

import info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.LoginActivity;

public class SessionManager {
    // LogCat tag
    private static String TAG = SessionManager.class.getSimpleName();
    // Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences pref;
    Editor editor;
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 1;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "OnlineShop";
    private static final String KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN = "isLoggedIn";
    // Email address (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";

    // Password (make variable public to access from outside)
    public static final String KEY_PASS = "password";

    //ID userid for the session
    public static final String KEY_ID="uid";



    public SessionManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Create login session
     * */
    public void createLoginSession(String email, String password, int uid){
        // Storing login value as TRUE
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);

        // Storing email in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

        // Storing password in pref
        editor.putString(KEY_PASS, password);

        //Storing userid uid in pref
        editor.putInt(KEY_ID, uid);
        // commit changes
        editor.commit();
    }

/*  public void setLogin(boolean isLoggedIn) {
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, isLoggedIn);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "User login session modified!");
    }
    */
    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     * */
    public void checkLogin(){
        // Check login status
        if(!this.isLoggedIn()){
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }
    /**
     * Get stored session data
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user email
        user.put(KEY_EMAIL, pref.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null));

        // user password
        user.put(KEY_PASS, pref.getString(KEY_PASS, null));

        //user id
        user.put(KEY_ID, pref.getString(KEY_ID, null));
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     * */
    public void logoutUser(){
        // Clearing all data from Shared Preferences
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


    public boolean isLoggedIn(){

        return pref.getBoolean(KEY_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
03-07 19:26:27.643 1795-1795/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: 
info.androidhive.loginandregistration, 
PID: 1795 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.loginandregistration/info.androidhive.loginandreg‌​istration.activity.MainActivity}: 
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
        'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: We'll need your LogCat, if it crashes. Otherwise we can't help you if we don't know _why_ it crashes.

Comment: Please place your logcat!

Comment: 03-07 19:26:27.643 1795-1795/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: info.androidhive.loginandregistration, PID: 1795
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.loginandregistration/info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with storing JSON values in SharedPreferences. The crash occurs for a different reason. In your MainActivity you are trying to read the contents of the Bundle, specifically the value of "status", but the problem is that you don't always put that extra value when you invoke your MainActivity, and most likely you don't check whether it's null before trying to read it. In one place you invoke it as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in another as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("status",status);
startActivity(intent);
```

So, implement some proper error handling in your MainActivity and you should get rid of this crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class SharedPreference {
            private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
            private Context mContext;
            private String KEY = "KEY";
            private String JSONKEY = "JSONKEY";


            public SharedPreference(Context mContext) {
                this.mContext = mContext;
                mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            }

        // for saving list in JSON format
            public boolean setList(List<String> list)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(list);
                prefsEditor.putString(KEY, json);
                return prefsEditor.commit();
            }
        // get list from json format
            public List<String> getList()
            {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = mPrefs.getString(KEY, "");
                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
                return gson.fromJson(json,type);
            }


        // Set Json
            public boolean setJson(JSONObject json)
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mPrefs.edit();
                String jsonString = json.toString();
                prefsEditor.putString(JSONKEY, jsonString);
                return prefsEditor.commit();
            }

        // get json
            public JSONObject getJson() throws JSONException {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String json = mPrefs.getString(JSONKEY, "");

                return new JSONObject(json);
            }


        }
```

You should get string like below to avoid null pointer Exception

```
// string can be null
   String status = getIntent().getStringExtra("status");

if(status!= null)
{
// do your work here
}
```